# Before completing the entire service file angularjs redirecting to main controller

Tags: angularjs

My application is first loading service file then based on the return value it should go to main controller. But my problem is,

- ) First my appService.js file is loading. But before going inside **this.app** function it is redirecting to main controller.And again it is coming back.
- ) In main controller I have written **appService.app()**. So first time i'm getting undefined for **"appservice.app()"**.
- ) My need is after entire line completed from service.js file only i need to go to main controller.

```js
app.service('appService', ['apiService', '$window', function(apiService, $window) {
    var mainAppList = [],appList;
    this.app = function() {
            try {
                var requestPromise = apiService.getAppList().then(function(response) {
                    appList = response.data;
                    appList = appList.filter(app => app.Environment == environment);
                    angular.forEach(appList, function(value, key) {
                        var app1 = "main" + value.AppType;
                        var app2 = value.appid;
                        var app = {
                            "AppType": app1,
                            "AppId": app2
                        }
                        mainAppList.push(app);
                    });
                    return mainAppList;
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.name + ': "' + err.message + '"')
            }           
    }}]);
});
```

And my main COntroller is,

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'appService', function($scope, appService) {
        var responseData = appService.app();
}]);
```

Here, First appService file only loading till the variable initialization of line number 2. After that it is going to main controller and again it is coming back to this.app function. So the returned value is not going properly to main controller.

This is very big challange to me. Can anyone please explain how to do this?

Comment: this.app function does not return any value

Comment: How can I achieve this? Can you please suggest any solution. How to modify this code?